# Print from Apache Storm Bolt

Tags: java, apache-storm

I'm working my way through the example code of some Storm topologies and bolts, but I'm running into something weird. My goal is to set up Kafka with Storm, so that Storm can process the messages available on the Kafka bus. I have the following bolt defined:

```
public class ReportBolt extends BaseRichBolt {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6102304822420418016L;

  private Map<String, Long> counts;
  private OutputCollector collector;

  @Override @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector outCollector) {
    collector = outCollector;
    counts = new HashMap<String, Long>();
  }

  @Override

  public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    // terminal bolt = does not emit anything
  }

  @Override
  public void execute(Tuple tuple) {   
    System.out.println("HELLO " + tuple);
  }

  @Override
  public void cleanup() {
    System.out.println("HELLO FINAL");
  }
}
```

In essence, it should just output each Kafka message; and when the cleanup function is called, a different message should appear.

I have looked at the worker logs, and I find the final message (i.e. "HELLO FINAL"), but the Kafka messages with "HELLO" are nowhere to be found. As far as I can tell this should be a simple printer bolt, but I can't see where I'm going wrong. The workers logs indicate I am connected to the Kafka bus (it fetches the offset etc.).

In short, why are my `println`'s not showing up in the worker logs?

**EDIT**

```
public class AckedTopology {

  private static final String SPOUT_ID = "monitoring_test_spout";
  private static final String REPORT_BOLT_ID = "acking-report-bolt";
  private static final String TOPOLOGY_NAME = "monitoring-topology";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int numSpoutExecutors = 1;

    KafkaSpout kspout = buildKafkaSpout();
    ReportBolt reportBolt = new ReportBolt();

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout(SPOUT_ID, kspout, numSpoutExecutors);
    builder.setBolt(REPORT_BOLT_ID, reportBolt);

    Config cfg = new Config();
    StormSubmitter.submitTopology(TOPOLOGY_NAME, cfg, builder.createTopology());
  }

  private static KafkaSpout buildKafkaSpout() {
    String zkHostPort = "URL";
    String topic = "TOPIC";

    String zkRoot = "/brokers";
    String zkSpoutId = "monitoring_test_spout_id";
    ZkHosts zkHosts = new ZkHosts(zkHostPort);

    SpoutConfig spoutCfg = new SpoutConfig(zkHosts, topic, zkRoot, zkSpoutId);
    KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutCfg);
    return kafkaSpout;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use println in the first place? Storm is supposed to use logback for logging to files. Also, println is bad for latency (IO).

Comment: share how do you build the topology .. is it chained properly with the spout?

Comment: @zenbeni I just want to check everything is working correctly. This is by no means the final solution, just a sanity check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bolt is not chained with the spout. You need to use storm's grouping in order to do that .. Use something like this

```
    builder.setBolt(REPORT_BOLT_ID, reportBolt).shuffleGrouping(SPOUT_ID);
```

The `setBolt` typically returns a [InputDeclarer](https://storm.apache.org/javadoc/apidocs/backtype/storm/topology/InputDeclarer.html) object. In your case by specifying `shuffleGrouping(SPOUT_ID)` you are telling storm that you are interested in consuming all the tuples emitted by component having id `REPORT_BOLT_ID`.

Read more on [stream groupings](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Concepts.html#stream-groupings) and choose the one based on your need.